# Fullcalendar Jquery plugin showing "fullcalendar not a function"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

[EDIT: Calendar shows but it's faulty!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcGKL.png) I am trying to include a Jquery fullcalendar plugin in my code, and it is not working.

The following simplistic code (NOT my actual project) works fine, but when I try to include the plugin in my actual project, it doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Jquery Fullcalandar Integration with PHP and Mysql</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: [{'id':1,'title':'dfdgdf','start': '2019-06-15T22:00:00','end': '2019-06-15T23:00:00', backgroundColor:'silver'}],
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
     var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
     if(title)
     {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Added Successfully");
       }
      })
     }
    },
    editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert('Event Update');
      }
     })
    },

    eventDrop:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function()
      {
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert("Event Updated");
      }
     });
    },

    eventClick:function(event)
    {
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
     {
      var id = event.id;
      $.ajax({
       url:"delete.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{id:id},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Event Removed");
       }
      })
     }
    },

   });
  });
   
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The following is code from my actual project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-74664112-6"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-74664112-6');
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!-- Materialize icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    

<h4 style="text-align:center;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Heading</h4>

<div id="calendar">

</div>

<script>
   
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable:true,
      header:{
       left:'prev,next today',
       center:'title',
       right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      events: [{'id':1,'title':'dfdgdf','start': '2019-06-15T22:00:00','end': '2019-06-15T23:00:00', backgroundColor:'silver'}],
      selectable:true,
      selectHelper:true,
      select: function(start, end, allDay)
      {
       var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
       if(title)
       {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
         url:"insert.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
         success:function()
         {
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          alert("Added Successfully");
         }
        })
       }
      },
      editable:true,
      eventResize:function(event)
      {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var title = event.title;
       var id = event.id;
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
        success:function(){
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
         alert('Event Update');
        }
       })
      },
  
      eventDrop:function(event)
      {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var title = event.title;
       var id = event.id;
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
        success:function()
        {
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
         alert("Event Updated");
        }
       });
      },
  
      eventClick:function(event)
      {
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
       {
        var id = event.id;
        $.ajax({
         url:"delete.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{id:id},
         success:function()
         {
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          alert("Event Removed");
         }
        })
       }
      },
  
     });
    });
     
</script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the console, I shouldn't be getting any kind of warnings/errors, but for some reason I'm getting a warning and error that says jquery.deferred exception and fullcalendar is not a function

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU8Mu.png)

Comment: You are talking about which plugin? Could you make it a little clear? Are you saying it is working standalone but is not running when you tried with your real projects?

Comment: I'm referring to the fullcalendar jquery plugin. Yes it works standalone, but it doesn't run when I've tried it with my real project. The code I've used in both versions is largely sourced from https://www.webslesson.info/2017/12/jquery-fullcalandar-integration-with-php-and-mysql.html .

Comment: And what error does it show? Is it the base calendar layout that does not load or is it that events do not load. Is there anything in console.log.

Comment: Snapsot of error can be found at https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU8Mu.png (at the bottom of the question) - the base calendar layout does not load at all.

Comment: If you click "run code snippet" under each of the two snippets of code included in the question, it shows the difference in output (one will show a calendar, one will give an error)

Comment: it looks like you are placing your script in a different order. Could you try with `moment.js`, `jquery`, `jquery ui` and `full-calendar js`

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "placing script in a different order"? also what exactly should I do with moment.js/jquery/jquery ui/full-calendar js? sorry I'm not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

Means order these library in that order

Comment: Changed the order to exactly this, but still doesn't work:

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

Comment: You are including jQuery **three** times (via different `<script` tags)! This is unnecessary, and careless, and can also lead to strange problems. Remove two of those tags (I suggest the first and last ones), you don't need them. Then see if it helps.

Comment: @SarojShrestha whether momentJS is included before jQuery or not makes no difference to anything. The important thing is that they are both included before fullCalendar, that they are not included more than once, and that the script files are actually succeeding in loading correctly (which can be checked via the browser's Network tool)

Comment: I have removed those two script tags - the calendar now appears, but it is faulty - I have edited the original question post with a link to a snapshot at the top (also found https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcGKL.png), showing the faulty calendar (with the multiple unnecessary scrolling bars across the calendar)

Comment: I would guess you probably have some CSS issues, maybe conflicts. Try to remove other CSS until you have only the fullCalendar CSS loaded, or until you find that removing one particular file makes the problem go away. That will help to see if I am right, and help you identify more precisely where the issue might be coming from

Comment: Yes I managed to find the css that was causing the issue - thanks so much ADyson and Saroj for all your help, I appreciate it immensely!